# Outlook 2010 add-in doesn't update after edit

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in

I have a problem developing an Outlook 2010 add-in in Visual Studio 2010.

When I create a blank add-in project and just add messagebox to the startup event saying 'Test' everything is ok. Outlook starts, installs the addin and shows the message.

Then I close the Outlook and change the string to 'Test1'. Rebuild the solution and run it and then it just says 'Test' again. It doesnt update the plugin itself.

What's wrong? How to force Outlook to update the add-in?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It should update automatically. You can try Build -> Clean solution (this unregisters the AddIn from the Outlook) then run it again.